# Golang: ssh running remote scripts: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, go, ssh

I'm using ssh module to run shell scripts on remote machine:

```
// ssh-run.go
package main
import (
    "bytes"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

var (
    flagUser = flag.String("user", "", "")
    flagPwd = flag.String("pwd", "", "")
    flagHost = flag.String("host", "", "")
    flagCmd = flag.String("cmd", "", "")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile | log.LstdFlags)

    cfg := ssh.ClientConfig {
        User: *flagUser,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod(ssh.Password(*flagPwd)),
    }

    // skip err checking for short code
    conn, _ := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:22", *flagHost), &cfg)
    defer conn.Close()
    ss, _ := conn.NewSession()
    defer ss.Close()

    var out bytes.Buffer
    ss.Stdout = &out
    ss.Stderr = &out
    ss.Run(*flagCmd)
    fmt.Printf("err: %v, out: %v\n", err, out.String())
}
```

On a remote Centos server(`sshd` is running), I put a simple Ping script under home path, and I run the demo:

```
go run ssh-run.go -cmd "/bin/bash /home/me/try_ping.sh" -host 172.17.0.2 -pwd 123456 -user me
```

I got the error:

```
err: Process exited with status 127, out: /bin/bash: /home/me/try_ping.sh: No such file or directory
```

But when the remote server is a Ubuntu server, the Ping script works well.

What is the difference between Centos and Ubuntu when facing remote script running? I need to run remote scripts under many UNIX-like OS, How to fix the gap between them?

Comment: Can you post the file permissions on remote server ?

Comment: @AndreaSessa: I have chmod +x the file.

Comment: Did you make sure to check case senitivity?

Comment: It's probably `sh` that's not found. Use an absolute path. Notice the error is coming from bash, if the file is executable, just remove the `sh`

Comment: @JimB: Whether the file is executable or not is not defined, the script is received from user end, so what I do is run them with `sh` or `bash`.

Comment: Show the exact string you're sending to be executed. If you're unnecessarily quoting the arguments, bash will look for a file literally named `"sh /abs/path/to/xx.sh"`. You can get the same error locally or running `ssh hostname '"sh /abs/path/to/xx.sh"'`.

Comment: That's a slightly different error now. There should be no difference here between a default ubuntu and centos configuration. Try debugging with some other tests, like sending `ls /home/me/try_ping.sh`, or do the equivalent using ssh on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I go the reason.  Normally, when we need to pass a long command to remote server via SSH, say `sh /path/to/script.sh`, we can run it via(single quote also works):

```
ssh user@1.2.3.4 "sh /path/to/script.sh"
```

here, we use double quote to disable shell parameter split.

While in my true golang code (above code is cut from my project and use flags for testing.), I also used double quote, and the golang SSH package also send the tow double quote to remote SSH server, then remote SSH don't know how to locate files prefixed with double quote.

The annoy things is that, the error message do not carry the double quote, blind me about the double quote.

Thanks @JimB :)